# How to program the in clause in tsql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code

```
declare @code nvarchar
set @code='2/2017,3/2017'

select *
from payroll
where id_code in (@code)
```

But I am getting an error in the where clause.

Comment: What you want to acheive exactly? and what is the error you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define variable to use with IN operator (T-SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707326/define-variable-to-use-with-in-operator-t-sql)

Comment: make it set @code = '''2/2017'',''3/2017'''

Comment: @TechGirl this will not work. first of all the type is `nvarchar` not a list, second it would have been single quotes

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle? That code wont run on both...

Comment: yes, also you will need to have dynamic query if string needs to be passed in where IN

Comment: thank you techgril ,yes i want dynamic query in the IN sql part

Comment: I am using sql server 2008

Comment: This is not Oracle related at all . Please remove the Oracle tag.

Comment: Can you use a table valued parameter instead of delimited string? If not you either need to use dynamic sql or a string splitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using **SQL Server 2016** you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

```
declare @code nvarchar
set @code='2/2017,3/2017'

select *
from payroll
where id_code in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@code,','))
```

for older versions of SQL you can use this as a guide [T-SQL split string based on delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768321/t-sql-split-string-based-on-delimiter)

Comment: Actually, I think the last bit should be `IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@code, ','))`.